# UNIX: how to zip a folder that contains more folders w/o including any of the folder paths

Tags: unix, zip

I' m trying to zip a folder that contains some .json files plus subfolders with more .json files. I need to zip the parent folder with everything included without containing any of the parent or subfolders paths. Is there any way I can do this?

Thank you

EDIT:

I want this:

```
 pending_provider/722c9cb2-268b-4e4a-9000-f7f65e586011-version/1d296136-ac87-424e-89c4-682a63c7b853.json (deflated 68%)
```

But not this:

```
pending_provider/722c9cb2-268b-4e4a-9000-f7f65e586011-version/ (stored 0%)
```

I want to avoid the "stor" compression type which only saves the folder path. I want only the "defN"
So the -j doesn't help me a lot

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any paths at all you could use the `-j` option. Below is the man page entry for the option.

```
   -j
   --junk-paths
          Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do  not  store
          directory  names.  By default, zip will store the full path (relative to 
          the current directory).
```

If you just want to exclude directories

```
   -D
   --no-dir-entries
          Do not create entries in the zip archive for directories.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I' ve tried this one, but it stores all my files like being in the same folder. I need to have the /folder/file paths but not the /folder paths. To be more specific ( I EDIT my post)

Comment: Does this do what you need? https://superuser.com/questions/312301/unix-zip-directory-but-excluded-specific-subdirectories-and-everything-within-t